# Improve performance by creating light and heavy versions of a class

Tags: php, performance, symfony

I finished some time ago an application, and I've started with the optimizations , but a couple of things that still have not been optimized , for example the save process , many will say that this is so simple you do not need to optimize it.

now my application has some specific requirements , all is exposed through JSON API . This led me to select a tool like JMSSerializer for the job serialization of objects. the problem is that I have several closely related entities , because the serialization recursively visit each property , this can become a big problem especially when you begin to aunmentar records . 50K , 100K or 1M . the JMS serialization becomes heavy and application response becomes slow .

JMS now provides tactics of exclusion , I am currently using the groups, but this has come back to hell, my question is: Is it bad to have two entities ( Light and Heavy ) for a table ? and is this possible ?

my question is focused on some properties of entities are edited through forms but most of the fields are not ( primarily those relationship with other entities )

may be that all this is mere stupidity that occurred to me in a moment of mental fatigue, but if I would like to read some opinion or proposal of how to avoid this without having to create complex rules of exclusion

hopefully so that solutions are focused and designed to work with the components of symfony and Doctrine

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is (part of) your answer:

```
% app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
The table with name 'foo.foo' already exists.
```

It might work in some cases (probably if not using any of the Schema/SchemaTool related stuff), however in many other cases it will get you into trouble.

A more conventional way would be to split the entity into two separate entities, one with only the "Light" parts, and the other with only the additional "Heavy" parts, and connect the two via a one-to-one relation. Then use serializer groups on the "Light" entity to control whether the "Heavy" parts will be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with serialization groups getting out of control and considered a couple of options. We ended up creating a naming scheme and using arrays to attempt to control the proliferation  of serialization groups.

In our entities, we name the serialization groups after the relationship. All of the base entity fields are just named after the entity (maybe abbreviated).

```
* @Groups({'EntityA_EntityB'})
```

Then we create arrays of serialization groups in the entity based on the usage

```
static $lightView = array('EntityA','EntityA_EntityB', 'EntityA_EntityC');
```

Then in the controller we can get the groups easily

```
private $viewGroup = array_merege(EntityA::$lightView, EntityC::$lightView);
```

It is really just a thin layer over the standard serialization groups, but it means we don't have to create so many groups, and they are all managed in one place (no scrolling through the entity adding to the annotation). All of our entities are serialized to json and sent to the client to be rendered in knockout.js, so I feel your pain trying to manage a growing list of serialization groups..

Comment: when you mean you do not have to scroll through the entire entity, you mean you only do it once right?

Comment: Right. If we want to add one of the relationships to the serialization group we just add it to the static array, not create a new group to add to the entity (and maybe other entities as well).